# Name disappeared from main menu bar

Tags: gnome-panel

I have Ubuntu 10.4. I installed a nvidia gigabyte geforce 210 graphic card because the intel graphic card is a disaster. I use a terminal and basic, fiddly adjustments were successfully made to get the window to fit the screen. The new card is a roaring success. Nothing freezes and visuals can be set to Extra. But, from that point on, my main menu bar misbehaved and icons kept disappearing. Logon and logoff usually helped. R-E-I-S-U-B was needed when the actual logoff icon disappeared. My full name, Anthony Burman, appeared in the main menu bar. It was alonside Wanda, the Fish , the Oracle.... My name disappeared and I cannot get it back. It can't be found anywhere in the 'add to panel' section. Indicator applet session also can't bring it back. How do i re-insert my name on the toolbar?
Thanks,
Ant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click an empty part on the panel and select add to panel,in the Add to Panel box select User Switcher, I believe that should put your full name back on the panel.

When you click on that particular applet a menu should show with; Account Information, System Preferences, Lock Screen, Switch User and Quit, the logout appears when you click Quit.

If you want just your username and menu items for logout, hibernate, shutdown etc. then select Indicator Applet Session.

Comment: There's no User Switcher in the box. In Applet Session, which wasn't deleted, I can click and "switch from Ant" but that never helped either.

Comment: Are you sure? You will have to scroll down, I think it is the fifth item from bottom, the box in question is the "Add To Panel" box, if it is not there i would say this is puzzling.

Answer (score 5):

Right click, add to panel, search for indicator applet, there should  be two of them, "indicator applet" and "indicator applet session." The latter is the "me menu" so add the latter! problem solved :D

Comment: Indicator applet session was never deleted. It's there, with all the relevant info including the logout icon. My name will show when I click on it. However my name appeared separately on the panel too and that is what disappeared.

Comment: This answered my question.  I blew right over that one and could only find the user switcher, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 1` this will change your user name for the one you put in about me, and I also had that problem and it was mostly for the suddenly change of resolution

Comment: Whoa. Didn't quite get that. Do I type the entire line into terminal? You sure I won't blow up? Thanks, ant.